# Using AddToHook instead of background package

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, backgrounds, coordinates

Recently I found out that the `background` package is deprecated and one should use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` (comments in [Positioning relative to page in XeLaTeX with package background and 'nested' tikzpictures 'dimension too large'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641641/positioning-relative-to-page-in-xelatex-with-package-background-and-nested-tik?noredirect=1#comment1599385_641641)) and I have seen an example in this post: [Migration background package > \AddToHook macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588238/migration-background-package-addtohook-macro)

However, for my use-case this conversion did not give the exact same results as the code written with `background` package. I want to keep using relative coordinates with `(0,0)` as the top-left of the page and `(1,1)` the bottom-right of the page, as given in: [Positioning relative to page in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz) by romain.bqt4.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[centering, margin = 2cm, bottom = 2.5cm, top = 1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\put(1cm,-\paperheight)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shift=(current page.north west)] % for XeLaTeX
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\node (logo) at (0.5, 0.95) {\piktjur};
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, line width = 2pt, red] (logo) -| (0.05, 0.025) -- (0.95, 0.025) |- (logo);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shift=(current page.north west)] % for XeLaTeX
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\node (logo) at (0.5, 0.95) {\piktjur};
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, line width = 2pt, blue] (logo) -| (0.05, 0.025) -- (0.95, 0.025) |- (logo);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand*{\piktjur}{\includegraphics[height = 2cm]{example-image.pdf}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

[image: mismatching borders]
Now, ideally I would like them to patch and I believe it has something do with the `\put` command. However, if that is not possible, it also causes the problem of the relative coordinate system not working as it is supposed to work. Specifically, changing the logo node to for example `(0.5, 0.925)` changes the height of the top horizontal part of the border. It even *lowers* the bar.

```
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\put(1cm,-\paperheight)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shift=(current page.north west)] % for XeLaTeX
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\node (logo) at (0.5, 0.925) {\piktjur};
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, line width = 2pt, red] (logo) -| (0.05, 0.025) -- (0.95, 0.025) |- (logo);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}
```

[image: weird relative coordinates]

**Question**

How do I need to change the code in order to:

1. have the borders match,
2. have the relative coordinate system working as expected?

Comment: I have answer your previous question. The method I used will show the boarder as your wanted.

Answer (score 2):

well the background package is not deprecated, but it uses internally tikz and so doesn't work well if you want to add a tikz picture.

Beside this I think you are overcomplicating with all the scope and remember picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[centering, margin = 2cm, bottom = 2.5cm, top = 1.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, calc}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
 {%
  \put(0,-\paperheight)
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\paperwidth,0)},y={(0,\paperheight)}] %
    \path[use as bounding box](0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \node (logo) at (0.5, 0.95) {\piktjur};
    \draw[rounded corners=10pt, line width = 2pt, red] (logo) -| (0.05, 0.025) -- (0.95, 0.025) |- (logo);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\newcommand*{\piktjur}{\includegraphics[height = 2cm]{example-image.pdf}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your solution doesn't match, the figure should be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Tom the code in the question used (0.5, 0.95) as coordinate and that is at the top. (assuming the 0,0 should be at the bottom left.

Comment: He wanna a relative positioning as a ratio of the page. Because he use the shaft and scope in tikz, So don't need `\put` command. The example picture he showing is also have the figure at the bottom

Comment: After the `shift=(current page.north west)` , (0,0) is not at bottom left anymore. It at 'top left' right now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed I orignally wanted `(0,0)` to be the top-left and `(1,1)` the bottom-right as that's how I wrote the rest of the code, even though it was contrary to normal cartesian coordinates. If you can change the code such that it does that, I will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should be work, if you wanna keep your original strategy. Delete `\put(0,-\paperheight)` and add `overlay` in `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.north west)]`:

```
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.north west)] % for XeLaTeX
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\node (logo) at (0.5, 0.925) {\piktjur};
\draw[rounded corners=10pt, line width = 2pt, red] (logo) -| (0.05, 0.025) -- (0.95, 0.025) |- (logo);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
}
```