# How to use image as page background

Tags: backgrounds, leaflet

I have an png image, I would like to integrate it into a latex leaflet.

I would like to put this image at the corner of the page as a background. But I can't get it to go outside of the margins.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,foldmark,notumble]{leaflet}
\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{5mm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}% <-- For English: Latin script here!

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand*\defaultmarker{\textsuperscript\textasteriskcentered}

\CutLine*{1}% Dotted line without scissors
\CutLine*{6}% Dotted line without scissors

\begin{document}
    
    %\begin{center}
    \vspace*{-0.8in}
    \hspace*{-0.8in}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        {\includegraphics{drawing.pdf}} % 
    \end{figure}
    
    This is the title
    

    \section{Abstract}
    
    This is the abstract which is good.
    \section{Background}
    
    \lipsum[2-4]
    
    \section{Objectives}
    
    \lipsum[5-7]
    
    \section{Techniques}
    
    \lipsum[8-10]
    
    \section{Results}
    
    \lipsum[11]
    
    % \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{esempio}
    
    \lipsum[12-13]
    
    \section{Conclusions}
    
    \lipsum[14]
    
    \section{Acknowledgements}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{Contact details}
    
    Nome Cognome {\tt nome.cognome@studium.unict.it}
    
\end{document}
```

Would it be also possible to write on top of the image? (i.e. consider it as a background?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: unrelated to your question, but I would suggest that if possible you should try to use a vector graphic like pdf instead of a png. A vector graphic won't get pixelated if your reader zooms in and given the simple graphic, the file size of your flyer will probably also be smaller.

Comment: You can use latex's hook mechanism to add elements to your background, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642026/36296 for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\usepackage{background}
```

Then adjust the alignment of background image on the page using

```
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  opacity=0.5,
  angle=0,
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background_image.jpg}}
}
```

Then use it in the main document

```
\begin{document}
\BgThispage
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer a lot, by adding a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be tested immediately. Usually it would be a good idea to use the code from the question and add or change only relevant parts. You can use an image from [package `mwe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) as example image. And please mark your code using markdown.

Comment: Thanks @chetan! This is exactly what I was missing.